# Cannot import name 'isin' Python with JAX

Tags: python, pip, jax

I wanted to make a deep learning model to run on my PC, but while it’s downloading it stops, because of the error message `cannot import name 'isin' from 'jax._src.numpy.lax_numpy'`

I have `numpy` and `jax` installed but it still gives me this error message. Is there any package I missed.(and some more)

EDIT: The dalle-flow-server https://github.com/jina-ai/dalle-flow and after writing `jina flow --uses flow.yml` it tries to execute a file and download a pre trained model and while it's doing that --> the Error appears.

Comment: While what is downloading?  How is it being downloaded?  Please provide at least the minimum details for someone to properly answer the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: how did you install jax and numpy? as part of the dalle-flow requirements.txt? or before that? i wonder if you might have a version conflict

Comment: are you certain `pip install -r requirements.txt` completed successfully?

Comment: @joel your comment was very helpful could you make it an answer. I am pretty new here and I don't think that I am able to do this.

Comment: which bit was helpful? Does it work now?

Comment: @joel The second one

Answer (score 2):

The version 0.3.5 release of JAX rearranged some of the private implementation, and `isin` is no longer part of the private `jax._src.numpy.lax_numpy` submodule.

Regardless of which JAX version you are using, the recommended import is

```py
from jax.numpy import isin
```

This will work correctly in any JAX version released in the last several years since the `isin` function was first added.

In general, you should avoid imports from any private submodule like `jax._src.numpy` (i.e. those starting with an underscore) because the contents may be subject to change in any release without warning. For public submodules like `jax.numpy`, any such changes will come with deprecation warnings for several releases before the imports are moved. See JAX's [API Compatibility Policy](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_compatibility.html) for more information.

If you are using a third party package that depends on private submodule imports, you may need to pin a particular jax & jaxlib version for it to work correctly. In this case it looks like you'll need the following:

```
$ pip install jax==0.3.4 jaxlib==0.3.2
```

You may wish to report this issue to the maintainers of dalle-flow, and suggest that they no longer rely on imports from private submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. It looks like it might not have completed successfully